# Ошибка при попытке записи данных в файл на Android 6.0.1

Tags: java, android

Есть следующий код:

```
public boolean write() {

    String jsonString = "";

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    ArrayList<SData> list = (ArrayList<SData>) getAll();
    for (SData s : list) {
        sb.append(s.toRawString() + "\n");
    }
    jsonString = sb.toString();

    boolean result = true;

    try {
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/sData.txt");
        FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(file);
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);
        out.write(jsonString);
        out.close();



    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        result = false;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        result = false;
    }


    return result;
}
```

На версиях  до api level 23 работает нормально, на 23  нужны разрешения, их  можно запросить так :

```
 private static final int REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 1;
    private static String[] PERMISSIONS_STORAGE = {
            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
    };
/**
 * Checks if the app has permission to write to device storage
 *
 * If the app does not has permission then the user will be prompted to grant permissions
 *
 * @param
 */
public  void verifyStoragePermissions() {
    // Check if we have write permission
    int permission = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(ListActivity.this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

    if (permission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // We don't have permission so prompt the user
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                ListActivity.this,
                PERMISSIONS_STORAGE,
                REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
        );
    }
}
```

но запрашиваются они в момент испольнения.

Вопрос, можно ли запрашивать эти разрешения в момент установки и если нет, то какие еще есть способы чтения\записи данных в файл не дожидаясь пока разрешение будет получено?

Comment: нет таких способов, для этого и были в 6ке введены эти разрешения что бы приложенка не писала ничего куда попало пока права пользователь не одобрит

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Таких способов нет, с версии 6.0 для увеличения безопасности были введены [Dangerous permissions](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html#perm-groups), которые вызываются в момент использования